# What kind of popup "Safe To Remove Hardware" in Windows

Tags: java, swing, popup

i am working on a java project and i want to display a message in popup like the popup of "Safe To Remove Hardware" occurred in the windows when we click on the Eject icon for USB Drives.
I want show my message in the same kind of popup using java code.

Comment: @Robin *"..so I do not forget those links"*  I have a text document containing the strings I often use in SO comments.  That is one of them - I just need to fill in the numeral and mark it **bold** (>0) or ***bold+italic*** (0). ;)

Answer (score 4):

Use the SystemTray class.

To create an icon with a tooltip, use something like this:

```
SystemTray tray = SystemTray.getSystemTray();
TrayIcon icon = new TrayIcon(....);
icon.setToolTip("I have finished my work");
icon.setActionListener(this);
tray.add(trayIcon);
```

Then in the class that displays the tooltip, implement the ActionListener interface to be informed when the user clicks on the icon and/or the tooltip (that's what the `setActionListener()` is for)

For more details refer to the Javadocs of SystemTray, TrayIcon and ActionListener

Comment: thanks for your feed back but i want to display message without taking any kind of input(I don't want to click on icon),just want show message when required.

Comment: The leave out the actionlistener callback

Answer (score 3):

You simply need to use the [displayMessage(...)](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/TrayIcon.html#displayMessage%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String,%20java.awt.TrayIcon.MessageType%29) method of the [TrayIcon](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/TrayIcon.html) class.
Try your hands on this code, is this what you wanted :

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.net.URL;
import javax.swing.*;

public class BalloonExample
{
    private void createAndDisplayGUI()
    {   
        TrayIcon trayIcon = new TrayIcon(createImage(
                        "/image/caIcon.png", "tray icon"));
        SystemTray tray = SystemTray.getSystemTray();               

        try 
        {
            tray.add(trayIcon);
        } 
        catch (AWTException e) 
        {
            System.out.println("TrayIcon could not be added.");
            return;
        }

        trayIcon.displayMessage("Balloon", "My First Balloon", TrayIcon.MessageType.INFO);
    }

    //Obtain the image URL
    protected static Image createImage(String path, String description) {
        URL imageURL = BalloonExample.class.getResource(path);

        if (imageURL == null) {
            System.err.println("Resource not found: " + path);
            return null;
        } else {
            return (new ImageIcon(imageURL, description)).getImage();
        }
    }

    public static void main(String... args)
    {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable()
        {
            public void run()
            {
                new BalloonExample().createAndDisplayGUI();
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: Ahha, You are MOST WELCOME and keep Smiling :-)

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at my question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10175930/whats-the-cartoon-speech-bubble-coming-from-the-notification-area-called-and-h). Basically that tooltip is a Balloon tip and you can use ShellNotifyIcon to create one.