# What's the cartoon speech bubble coming from the notification area called, and how do I create one?

Tags: delphi, notifications, terminology

Can some one tell me what the name of the following popup window is:

[image: Speech bubble coming from Windows Messenger shell notification icon]

How do I create such a popup for my application?

Comment: it's a "nutifier"...a notification for the nuts.

Comment: @az01 : please post relevant answers.

Comment: ok, but so far it was just a comment. Anyway...I keep this on mind for my next answer.

Comment: Ah c'mon @CyprUS it was a bit of fun :). And IMHO, in XP at least they are dreadful, horrible things that are just distracting hence az01's comment I suspect.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

To be more specific, this is indeed called a **[Notification](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa511497.aspx)** (a specific type of balloon)<sup>[see also here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa511451.aspx)</sup>  and the icon from which it comes from is called a **Notification area Icon**.

The area of the screen in which this icon is located is called the **[Notification Area](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa511448.aspx)**. This is not specific to Windows - other operating systems have their own form of Notification Areas.

The correct way to manage a Notification Icon (or more, if you need to) from Windows is to use the **[Shell_NotifyIcon](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb762159%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)** API.

You can also use the numerous components available online wrapping this functionality (CoolTrayIcon is a prime example, although it is a bit bloated). You can make your own too, it's fairly easy.

Remember to follow the MSDN guidelines for correct use of this icon and good practices.

Answer (score 2):

I seem to have found out the answer, it is called a balloon notification . the relevant code to create one is found at :
http://swissdelphicenter.ch/torry/showcode.php?id=1164

Comment: There are many examples of things that will add the icon and do some other tasks.  As for the balloon notifications, they are indeed seen as annoying.  To that end, I should note that they can be permanently disabled within a system, so don't get too dependent on your app being able to show them.  See Microsoft KB #307729 for details about this and how to implement it (or to check for it).

Answer (score 0):

TMS component suite has better notification tools.You can check those out